# Differential equation first order what have I done wrong?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform, differential

\begin{align}
& f'(x) + 4f(x) = 6e^{-2x}; \quad f(0) = 1 \\
\implies & s \mathscr{F}(s) - f(0) + 4 \mathscr{F}(s) = \dfrac{6}{s+2} \\
\implies & \mathscr{F}(s)(s+4)= \dfrac{6}{s+2} - 1 \\
\implies & \mathscr{F}(s)(s+4)= \dfrac{6-s-2}{s+2} \\
\implies & \mathscr{F}(s)= \dfrac{4-s}{(s+2)(s+4)} = \dfrac{A}{s+2} - \dfrac{B}{s+4} 
\end{align}

Using partial fraction, we have
\begin{align}
& 4-s = A(s+4) - B(s+2) \\
\implies & 4 (-2+4)-(-1)(-4+2) = 4-2 \\
\implies & \dfrac{4}{s+2} - \dfrac{2}{s+4} \rightarrow (4e^{-2x}) - (2e^{-4x}) 
\end{align}

But it should be $e^{-4x}(3e^{2x} - 2$)

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  Thanks for showing your work. But please use MathJax so that we can read it.

Comment: Hint: I have edited until the first mistake that I spotted. Can you edit similarly the rest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The given eqn:$$\ f'(x)+4f(x) = 6e^{-2x} ; f(0) = 1$$
Or, it can be written as:$$\ \frac{dy}{dx}+4y = 6e^{-2x}$$This is linear differential equation in $\ y$ and hence its integrating factor(I.F):
$$\ e^{\int 4dx} = e^{4x}$$
Hence solution is : $$\ y(e^{4x}) = 6\int e^{-2x}.e^{4x}dx + c$$$$\ y(e^{4x}) = 6\int e^{2x}dx + c$$$$\ y(e^{4x}) = 6(\frac{e^{2x}}{2}) + c$$$$\ y(e^{4x}) = 3e^{2x} + c$$Now , when $\ x = 0, y = 1$.Therefore putting these values in last eqn:$$\ 1(e^0) = 3e^0 + c$$$$\ c = (-2)$$
Therefore the solution is:$$\ y = 3e^{-2x} - 2e^{-4x}$$$$\ f(x) = 3e^{-2x} - 2e^{-4x}$$

Comment: Joe we are unable to understand your process . Please use MathJax..

Answer (score 0):

Here you made a sign mistake

$$ \mathscr{F}(s)(s+4)= \dfrac{6}{s+2} \color {red}{- 1} $$

Should be $+f(0)=+1$

Then

$$ \mathscr{F}(s)= \dfrac{(s+8)}{(s+4)(s+2)} =\dfrac{A}{(s+2)}+\dfrac{B}{(s+4)} \to A=3, B=-2$$
The solution is 
$$f(x)=3e^{-2x}-2e^{-4x}$$